# npm not allowing installation of packages - npm ERR! Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install react in this new project but Npm won't let me install any module ( not even Express )

Here is what happens when I try creating an app...

```
@DESKTOP-AV5KJN8 MINGW64 ~/Documents/CodeProjects/test
$ npx create-react-app test-app

npm ERR! Unexpected end of input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-14T22_13_20_258Z-debug-0.log
```

The same issue occurs when trying to install literally any other npm package.

Here is a simplified version of the error log:

```
28 verbose stack C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\advisory.js:326
28 verbose stack       // then walk it forward until we hit a version without a
28 verbose stack                                                               
28 verbose stack
28 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
28 verbose stack     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
28 verbose stack     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
28 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
28 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
28 verbose stack     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
28 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
28 verbose stack     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
28 verbose stack     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
28 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\index.js:6:18)
28 verbose stack     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
29 verbose cwd C:\Users\Me\Documents\CodeProjects\test
30 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
31 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "test-app"
32 verbose node v17.3.1
33 verbose npm  v8.3.0
34 error Unexpected end of input
35 verbose exit 1
36 timing npm Completed in 239ms
37 verbose code 1
38 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
38 error     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-14T22_15_53_464Z-debug-0.log
```

Does anyone have any input on how to fix this?

I have tried clearing the cache using but encountered the following :

```
$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

The versions I'm running are the following:

- node v17.3.1
- npm  v8.3.0

Going to %appdata% and manually deleting npm-cache does not solve the issue. I have also tried reinstalling Node several times with the same outcome.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: What happens with commands like `npm init -y`, `npm install express`?

Comment: Hello there!

On both instances I encounter the following:


npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-14T22_43_25_804Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: try npm cache clean --force

Comment: unfortunately, the command only returns "npm WARN ... Recommended protections disabled"

Comment: Does this also happen in an empty directory?  `mkdir foo`, `cd foo`, `npm init -y`

Comment: sadly, it happens in any directory in my computer. I have tried reinstalling node several times and cant figure out why yet.

Comment: Try deleting cache manually. Type in windows search -> run -> %appdata% -> delete npm-cache folder. Also, just a suggestion try to always use LTS version of node (16.13.2).

Comment: Deleted cache folder manually, uninstalled node, and used the LTS version instead. No luck. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

Here are the steps I took:

- Uninstall node
- Manually clearing all cache using ->run->%appdata%
- Manually deleting all NPM files/folders remaining after uninstalling ( uninstalling does not delete some modules)
- Install Node LTS

All features in npm are now working. Thanks, everyone for your input!